# Telephone call from AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, air, voip, skype

Since there is no actionscript API for skype, is there a http call API which I can use for actionscript 3? I want to make telephone calls from AIR app.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://www.ribbit.com/platform/ Its the only solution I know of, and while I've never worked with it myself I have heard really good things.

Comment: is it possible to have real-time two-way communication using REST APIs?

Comment: two papers define the the possible use of Representational State Transfer (REST) based architectures for real time communications : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140366410001520 and http://www.springerlink.com/content/lr5r3t577m016882/

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has created a product which allows this: 
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashmedia_gateway/

Comment: thanks..its still pre-release and can't use it beyond developer 10 calls. has anyone tried it?  https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=labs_flashmedia_gateway

Answer (score 1):

There's always red5phone, if air is backwards compatible with flash.

Answer (score 1):

[Twilio Client](http://www.twilio.com/api/client) is a simple JavaScript and Flash based softphone that allows you to send and receive calls from a browser. It should work great from Adobe Air, though I haven't tried it yet.

(I work for Twilio)

Comment: what is the architecture for this kind of cloud communication?